# Angular with Three JS - canvas rendered in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, three.js, webgl

I'm currently developing code for a website and I'm trying to combine Three JS with Angular.
After a couple of research, I've discovered that this is possible and I did indeed manage to combine these two libraries.

My problem is that, when rendering the canvas, it either doesn't get displayed in the right component's container or it simply gets displayed in the root of the project.

Below I present two illustrations of the problem and also the main part of the code:

[Illustration of the canvas not being rendered in the component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8sxn.png)

[Illustration of the canvas being displayed on top of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCOhq.png)

Code:

```js
download() {
    
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 100 / 100, 0.1, 1000);

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: canvas,
      antialias: true,
      alpha: true,
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(100, 100);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    camera.position.z = 5;

    var animate = function () {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);

      cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    animate();
  }
```

```css
input[type="text"],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <h2 class="text-center"><i>Contact me:</i></h2>

  <form (ngSubmit)="sendEmail">

    <label class="text-center" for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="emailTitle" name="title" formControlName="title" placeholder="The title of the email..">


    <div class="form-floating">
      <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Write your email here" style="max-height: 200px;  white-space: normal"
        id="floatingTextarea"></textarea>
      <label for="floatingTextarea">Email text</label>
    </div>

    <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-evenly">
      <button type="button" disabled class="btn btn-primary .btn-lg">button 1</button>

      <canvas id="canvas" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;"></canvas>
      <a (click)="download()" class="btn btn-danger" role="button" href="../../../assets/files/cv.pdf" download="proposed_file_name">
        button 2
      </a>

    </div>

  </form>


</div>
```

If someone has a clue on how to fix this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);` after you initiate the Renderer. This essentially takes the `<canvas>` out of its existing position, and places it directly as a child of `<body>`. You can see it in your screenshot, it gets placed at the bottom of the `<body>` element, under all your scripts:
[image]

Just get rid of that line, and your canvas will remain where you initially put it, undisturbed.

Comment: Jesus christ man, thank you very much. You saved my day. I spent days trying to find the solution! Best regards

Comment: You’re welcome. You can accept it as the answer if it solved your problem :)